# In React Native navigation when using bottomTabs app stops

Tags: react-native, wix-react-native-navigation

Below is my code for bottomTabs that is not working, don't worry my component names are correct, I have checked many times. The only thing is when below code loads my apps stops working , by the way i am testing it in android (tried in simulator as well as on real device ) but not working.
What may be the possible reasons? I am new to react-native

```
const startTabs = () => {
Navigation.setRoot({
  root: {
    bottomTabs: {
      children: [
        {
          component: {
            name: 'awesome-places.SharePlaceScreen',
            passProps: {
              text: 'This is tab 1',
              myFunction: () => 'Hello from a function!',
            },
          },
        },
        {
          component: {
            name: 'awesome-places.FindPlaceScreen',
            passProps: {
              text: 'This is tab 2',
            },
          },
        },
      ],
    },
  }
 });
}
```

Comment: does the app shows any error or it just crashes or freezes ?

Comment: Doesn't show any error it just crashes..!

Comment: Solved the problem.
Actually in android icons are mandatory otherwise app will fail.